# Reacting to parameter changes in Vue component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Disclaimer - react dev learning vue.

I have a vue 3 project using composition api. All I want it to do is allow the user to enter some criteria, hit submit and display results. Simplified component structure looks like this:

[image]

`TheSidebar` component allows the user to enter search criteria and submit. This emits an event to the parent `SearchView` component which in turn passes the criteria to the `TheResults` component via props. Standard vue so far and all works.
[image]

What I am wanting is that the `TheResults` component will use the criteria (whenever updated) to perform a search and display the results.

In react I would simply use a useEffect hook with a prop parameter to check for an update to the criteria prop, perform a search and then update a local state variable with the search result.

This was the vue equivalent I came up with:

**TheResults.vue**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { onUpdated, ref } from "vue";
    import { type SearchCriteria } from '@/types/SearchCriteria';
    import { getCellLocations } from "@/actions/cellLocations";
    import { type CellLocation } from "@/types/CellLocation";

    const cellSites = ref<{data: CellLocation[], isLoading: boolean}>({data: [], isLoading: false});

    interface IProps {
        searchCriteria: SearchCriteria | undefined;
    }

    const props = defineProps<IProps>();

    onUpdated(async () => {
        if(props.searchCriteria) {
            cellSites.value = {data: [], isLoading: true};

            let results = await getCellLocations(props.searchCriteria);
            cellSites.value = {data: results, isLoading: false};
        }
    });
</script>

<template>
    <loader v-if="cellSites.isLoading" size="small" type="pulsing" />
    <span v-else>else</span>
</template>
```

This results in an endless loop because I'm updating `cellSites` value. Its also not specifically reacting to the criteria prop changing.

One way I can see around this is to perform the search in the `SearchView` component in the `handleOnSubmit` event handler and pass the results as a prop to `TheResults` however I wanted to keep the search logic out of the parent as its not its area of concern.

**SearchView.vue**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref } from "vue";

    import type { SearchCriteria } from '@/types/SearchCriteria';
    import TheSidebar from '@/components/search/TheSidebar.vue'
    import TheResults from "@/components/search/TheResults.vue";

    const searchCriteria = ref<SearchCriteria | undefined>();

    const handleOnSearch = (criteria: SearchCriteria) => {
        searchCriteria.value = criteria;
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div class="q-main-with-sidebar">
        <TheSidebar @search="handleOnSearch" />
        <main>
            <TheResults :searchCriteria="searchCriteria" />
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
```

What is it I need to do to have `TheResults` component perform a search when the criteria changes?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to use a computed like getCellSites that perform a search based on the props search-criteria ? If yes it's maybe because you are using a ref for an object, what I personnaly recommend is splitting your only ref into two : cellSites and isLoading, cellSites would be a ref of type CellLocation[] and isLoading a ref of type boolean. You will no longer need a onUpdated hook.

Comment: you need to watch the prop : https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use watch instead of onUpdate to react to search string changes.

I have implemented a sample code block with align to your problem. copied all vue snippets to codepen

```
Click [here](https://codepen.io/sgangumalla/pen/xxQyVNq)
```